# Confusion on :$f : V \rightarrow W$ is continuous if and only if for all open sets $U \subseteq W$ the set $f^{-1}(U)$ is also open$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In a recent assignment of mine at university I proved the following proposition;

Let $(V,||.||_V)$ and $(W,||.||_W)$ be two normed vector spaces and $f:V \rightarrow W$ a function. Under these hypothesis, $f$ is continuous if, and only if, the pre-image of every open set $U \subseteq W$ is also open.

Now I have proven this proposition (both directions), and my proof has convinced me. However when trying to prove this I came up with the following;

Consider the piece-wise function $f: (0,6) \rightarrow (0,4)$ defined by

$$ 
f(x) =
 \begin{cases} 
      x^2, &0 <x<2\\
      \frac{-1}{2}x+3 & 2\leq x <6 
   \end{cases}
$$

which is obviously discontinuous only at $x=2$. However if  $U = (0,4)$ then $f^{-1}(U) = (0,6)$, both of which are open sets, but $f$ is not continuous. Thus we contradict the proposition.

Obviously there is a flaw in my logic somewhere or I have misunderstood the proposition. So I put it to you to point out the error or misunderstanding.

Comment: The flaw in your logic isn't that you found an example of an open set such that the preimage is open..... the flaw in your logic is that you didn't show that EVERY pre-image of an open set is open.  If you did THAT and you knew the function was continuous, then that would be a contradiction.... but that's not the case; and, indeed, the preimage of $(1,3)$ is not open.

Comment: Thank you,  I see that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preimage must be open for all open sets.

The preimage of $(0,3)$ is not open, so the function is not continuous.